# Regex Groups doesn't return expected values

Tags: c#, regex

I tried the following code in the C# interactive of Visual Studio

```
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
> var re = new Regex(@"(\d\d/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d)");
> var r = re.Match("01/01/2016 02/02/2016").Groups;
> r
GroupCollection(2) { [01/01/2016], [01/01/2016] }
```

Why it doesn't return the expected `[01/01/2016], [02/02/2016]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to contain the first match twice because `Groups[0]` contains the entire matching string and the actual capture groups you define don't start until `Groups[1]`.

You will see this clearer with multiple capture groups:

```
> var re = new Regex(@"(\d)-([A-Z])");
> var r = re.Match("5-D").Groups;

> r[0]
{5-D}
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]: {5-D}
    base {System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture}: {5-D}
    Captures: {System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection}
    Success: true
> r[1]
{5}
    base {System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture}: {5}
    Captures: {System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection}
    Success: true
> r[2]
{D}
    base {System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture}: {D}
    Captures: {System.Text.RegularExpressions.CaptureCollection}
    Success: true
```

But what you want to do in your case is to use [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a regular expression.

## Use group names

To avoid the `0` based index confusion, and other confusions, named groups are useful:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?<date>\d\d/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d)");
var dateGroup = re.Match("01/01/2016").Groups["date"];
```

Comment: The pattern should be `var re = new Regex(@"(\d)");`. It's very misleading that `re.Match("....").Groups` still returns a collection with length of 2.

Comment: I think my example is clearer now, the two capture groups are now completely different. It is misleading, I agree. I tend to use named groups, see my edit.